# SQL query to get forward value based on some condition? (Without using window function)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 columns - Date and status

```
CampaignID     Date          Status    
123            2019-07-10    Active
123            2019-07-09    Paused 
123            2019-07-08    Paused
123            2019-07-07    Active
123            2019-07-06    Paused
```

Let's consider this is the campaign's data and we need to find the next active date of campaign in the new column as `active_date` given below.
E.g if campaign is paused on date, then I need the next date (in a new column) whenever the campaign is active.
Help me with the SQL query without using window functions, as my DB does not support window functions.

```
CampaignID  Date          Status      Active_date
123         2019-07-10    Active      
123         2019-07-09    Paused      2019-07-10
123         2019-07-08    Paused      2019-07-10 
123         2019-07-07    Active       
123         2019-07-06    Paused      2019-07-07
```

Comment: Is there a primary key? Or is it guaranteed that `date` is unique per `campaignid`?

Comment: @stickybit Date is not unique

Comment: When you use some expression for rows ordering then this expression MUST be unique. Imagine - there exists 2 rows for some date with different statuses - does for a row with 'Paused' status the matching 'Active' date is the same date or the next date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a correlated subquery to populate the last active date column:

```
SELECT
    CampaignID,
    Date,
    Status,
    CASE WHEN Status <> 'Active' THEN
         (SELECT t2.Date FROM yourTable t2
          WHERE t2.CampaignID = t1.CampaignID AND t2.Date > t1.Date AND t2.Status = 'Active'
          ORDER BY t2.Date LIMIT 1) END AS Active_Date
FROM yourTable t1
ORDER BY
    CampaignID,
    Date DESC;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo

The basic logic used above is straightforward.  For each record whose status is *not* active, the correlated subquery looks ahead and tries to find the date of the nearest record whose status *is* active.  We also only perform this lookup for records all belonging to the same campaign.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using window functions:

```
select t.*,
       (case when status <> 'Active'
             then min(case when status = 'Active' then Date end) over (partition by CampaignId order by date desc)
        end) as next_active
from t
order by CampaignID, Date desc;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=34f499f89e51589897e153be1b3e9b8d) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Unfortunately, my sql version does not support window function but thanks

Comment: @AniketGhole . . . You should upgrade.